# Where to start - Password hashing

Tags: algorithm, wordpress, passwords, hash

I've been setting up a Wordpress site and I've just been reading up about storing passwords in your database, and password hashing. I understand the whole concept- that it's an algorithm that translates the password to a (seemingly) random hexadecimal string, but does so in a predictable way, so the passwords can be stored and used again for checking at login.

Got that. To implement this, where do I start? What do I download, where does it go within my site directory, how do I call it, etc. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also, not picky about which hashing algorithm to use, I hear MD5 and SHA-1 are the best.

Comment: I'd suggest something like bcrypt because while MD5 and SHA-1 are good at hashing, they are not ideal for password security.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/bcrypt

Comment: wordpress already hashes the passwords, as do most modern web apps with logins - this is why your password is reset on most sites, as they can't send you your password when they don't know it . . . .

Comment: MD5 is *not* the best. In fact, it's badly enough broken that it should generally be avoided for anything security related. The known attacks don't (necessarily) cause a problem for this specific situation, but they're significant enough that it's best avoided.

Comment: You should definitely use a library for this, and not write any of your own code to actually compute the hash sum. There's a lot more to it, like iterating the hash and using salt. Hopefully there is a `bcrypt` implementation that you can use, but how to configure it for Wordpress is probably a question better posed on the [Wordpress site.](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 4):

Don't worry. By default, wordpress already hashes passwords. Unless you are modifying the code yourself, it should already be taken care of.